# Cypress not running with react-app-rewired

Tags: cypress, testing-library, react-app-rewired

I am trying to run cypress tests with reac-app-rewired but somehow I cannot get it working.
It appears as if cypress is not able to detect the config-overrides.js file in my project and I keep getting the following error when I run the command **npm run ci-test**

[image]

I have tried steps provided in https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/328 and https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22521 but it does not help.

**config-overrides.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const jest = require("jest");
module.exports = {
  jest: (config) => {
    config.globals["ts-jest"] = {
      babelConfig: {
        plugins: ["dynamic-import-node"],
      },
    };
    return config;
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
    Object.assign(fallback, {
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      assert: require.resolve("assert"),
      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
      url: require.resolve("url"),
      "process/browser": require.resolve("process/browser"),
      path: false,
      fs: false,
      timers: false,
    });
    config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: "process/browser",
        Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
      }),
    ]);
    return config;
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pogomaintenance",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "dynamic-import-node"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@backyard/design-tokens": "^2.13.0",
    "@backyard/icons": "^2.14.0",
    "@backyard/react": "^2.13.2",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.15",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.1",
    "@redux-saga/core": "^1.1.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "cosmiconfig": "^7.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "dateformat": "5.0.2",
    "excel-date-to-js": "^1.1.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minio": "^7.0.32",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.40",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.1",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^2.0.12",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "start-ci": "cross-env PORT=3001 BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "styleguide": "styleguidist server",
    "styleguide:build": "styleguidist build",
    "cypress-install": "node_modules/.bin/cypress install",
    "cypress": "react-app-rewired node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
    "cypress-cli-e2e": "node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec **/*.feature -e TAGS='not @ignore' --config baseUrl=http://localhost:3001/sc-pogomaintenance",
    "cypress-cli-component": "node_modules/.bin/cypress run --component",
    "ci-test": "start-server-and-test start-ci http-get://localhost:3001 cypress-cli-e2e"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "stepDefinitions": [
      "cypress/e2e/**/*.spec.js"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!<rootDir>/src/index.js",
      "!<rootDir>/src/reportWebVitals.js"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.5.1",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.3",
    "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill": "^0.1.4",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.5.0",
    "cypress": "^12.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "react-styleguidist": "^11.1.7",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "homepage": "/sc-pogomaintenance"
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: ["dynamic-import-node"],
};
```

**cypress.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  video: false,
  screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  viewportWidth: 1000,
  viewportHeight: 1000,
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require("./cypress/plugins/index.js")(on, config);
    },
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000/sc-pogomaintenance",
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/*.{feature,features}",
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/component/*.cy.js",
  },
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
I had to use

```
"start-ci": "cross-env PORT=3001 BROWSER=none react-app-rewired start"
```

instead of

```
"start-ci": "cross-env PORT=3001 BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
```